# How to use Google Calendar from Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

Anyone has a recent good start (or course) to access a Google Calendar from `ROR` and manipulate it.  I managed to login via  the `'omniauth-google-oauth2'` gem but cannot succeed using the `'google-api-client'` or is there another way? I'm new to `Ruby` and `ROR`.

Comment: http://readysteadycode.com/howto-access-the-google-calendar-api-with-ruby check this link

Answer (score 0):

didn't work with G. calendara but maybe try this gem https://github.com/northworld/google_calendar

so open Gemfile

```
# Gemfile

# ...
gem 'google_calendar'
# ...
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

that should install the gem, then just follow the instructions in Readme

Comment: you can use Ruby Toolbox to find more helpfull gems https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=google+calendar